# How to check div has image or not?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```
<div id="pl6" style="height: 123px; width: 135px;float:left" onmousedown="test(6);" ondrop="dropIt(event,6);" ondragover="event.preventDefault();">
<img src="6.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragIt(event,6);" id="pic6" />
</div>
```

I want to check if this div has an image or not using JavaScript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could do:

```
var divEle = document.getElementById("pl6");
if( divEle.getElementsByTagName('img').length > 0 ) {
   //has image element
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply:

```
if(document.querySelectorAll("#pl6 img").length > 0) {
   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(document.getElementById("pic6").length > 0){
  //...
}
```